# http server in python. problem when tring to response 404 not found

Tags: python, http, http-status-code-404, httpserver

I build a HTTP server that listening for clients, getting from them a GET requests, and reply response from the the directory of my computer. like a server.

```
import socket
import os


IP = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 80
SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 0.1
DEFAULT_URL = '\\index.html'
ROOT = 'C:\\work\\http_server\\webroot'


def get_file_data(filename):
    """ Get data from file """
    file = open(filename, 'rb')
    file_data = file.read()
    file.close()
    return file_data


def handle_client_request(resource, client_socket):
    """ Check the required resource, generate proper HTTP response and send to client"""

    if resource == '\\':
        url = ROOT + DEFAULT_URL
    else:
        url = ROOT + resource

    if not os.path.isfile(url):
        http_header = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n'
        http_response = http_header.encode()
    else:
        data = get_file_data(url)
    
        filetype = url.split('.')[-1]

        http_header = ''

        if filetype == 'html':
            http_header = 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n'
            http_header = http_header + str(len(data)) + '\r\n\r\n'
        ''' 
            elif filetype == 'jpg':
        '''
        
        http_response = http_header.encode() + data

    client_socket.send(http_response)


def validate_http_request(request):
    """
    Check if request is a valid HTTP request and returns TRUE / FALSE and the requested URL
    """
    splited = request.split('\r\n')
    first_line = splited[0]
    first_line = first_line.split(' ')
    if first_line[0] != 'GET':
        return False, 'null'
    elif first_line[2] != 'HTTP/1.1':
        return False, 'null'
    else:
        return True, first_line[1].replace('/', '\\')


def handle_client(client_socket):
    """ Handles client requests: verifies client's requests are legal HTTP, calls function to handle the requests """
    print('Client connected')

    while True:
        client_request = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        valid_http, resource = validate_http_request(client_request)
        if valid_http:
            print('Got a valid HTTP request')
            handle_client_request(resource, client_socket)
            break
        else:
            print('Error: Not a valid HTTP request')
            break

    print("client sent: ", resource)
    print('Closing connection')
    print('-------------------------------------------------')
    client_socket.close()


def main():
    # Open a socket and loop forever while waiting for clients
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))
    server_socket.listen()
    print("Listening for connections on port {}".format(PORT))

    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        print('New connection received')
        client_socket.settimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT)
        handle_client(client_socket)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Call the main handler function
    main()
```

when handle_client is the func that handle every single client that connected, checks if it an HTTP get request and, and if it TRUE, sending it to *handle_client_request* to handle it.

I added this code:

```
 if not os.path.isfile(url):
        http_header = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n'
        http_response = http_header.encode()
```

to check if the file isn't exist, so it will return 404 response..
but, when I run the server, and try in the browser in 127.0.0.1 to get the pages, so when its exist, everything is good. but in 404 case, it send to the browser 404 , but as I understand, the browser send more requests so the program stucked in this line in the handle_client func:

```
client_request = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
```

and get this timeout error:

```
socket.timeout: timed out
```

can someone help me?